# Is callback of an async function put in the message queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, asynccallback

I am new to Javascript, In the following code

```
    async function fun(callback) {
      callback();
    }
    
    console.log('1');
    fun(function(){
      console.log('2');
    });
    console.log('3');
```

The order of execution seems to be 1,2,3. But callback of an asynchronous function is put in the message queue and executed only after call stack is empty, so shouldn't the order be 1 3 2 ?

Comment: No. There is no message queue anywhere here, and your `async` function doesn't `await` anything asynchronous. It's just synchronous code with an unused promise thrown in.

Comment: Declaring a function `async` doesn't actually make it run asynchronously. It just wraps it in code that returns a promise, and allows it to use `await`.

Comment: The console log order is 1 3 2 if you put an `await` (like `await null;`) before `callback();`.